# Clone table data input values to entire row onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below table I want to change the input value for first row become `value="1"` onclick the copy button.

This `value="1"` when I entered manually and the value should repeat to the entire row when I click the copy button.

**Note:** I couldn't found any script regarding this to add the tried code.

Kindly comment below for further clarification.

[image: explanation]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="11">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="11">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is the script you tried?

Comment: Look for `$(this).closest("tr").find("input").each(...)`

Comment: @mplungjan I am not tried any script so far. Is it possible to do that.

Comment: I just gave you the start. Try it out

Comment: I don't know how to setup code from your syntax

Comment: Then how are you supposed to complete the task? It is very simple jQuery.

Comment: I am looking the snippet or fiddle solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy this first value to the rest:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-success").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link 
    var $inputs = $(this).closest("tr").find("input");
    var val = $inputs.eq(0).val(); // take the first
    $inputs.val(val); 
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="11">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="11">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think he wants the value to be changed to 1 (if 1 was the keyed in value), not add 1 to it like a string.

Comment: I think you got the wrong guy, it was someone else asking that question.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
$('.table a.btn').click(function() {
  var inputVal = $(this).prev().val();
  var td = $(this).closest("td");
  var sib = td.siblings().find("input");
  sib.val(inputVal)
});
```

This will take the value from the `input` associated with the `link/button` and put that value into the other `input`'s on the same `tr`

**Demo**

```js
$('.table a.btn').click(function() {
  var inputVal = $(this).prev().val();
  var td = $(this).closest("td");
  var sib = td.siblings().find("input");
  sib.val(inputVal)
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="11">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="11">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, this is nice!

Comment: Is it possible to place the button outside?

Comment: Well, yes, but you must find a way to find the associated input fields (either by class names or IDs).

Answer (score 1):

This JS code could be helpful.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.table a.btn').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var fieldVal = jQuery(this).siblings('.form-control').val();
        jQuery(this).parent('td').siblings('td').children('.form-control').val(fieldVal);
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="11">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="11">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the value of input using `prev()` inside click handler of the copy button.
Find parent td using closest and then get all its sibling tds. find input inside sibling tds and append first input value to the input existing values

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.btn.btn-success').on('click', function(){
      var val = $(this).prev('input').val();
      var $td = $(this).closest('td');
      var $siblings = $td.siblings();
      //to append values
      /*$siblings.find('input.form-control').each(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).val() + val);
      });*/

   // to replace values
     $siblings.find('input.form-control').val(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="11">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="11">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer the question "Is it possible to place the button outside?":

Here is a version with the button in front of all the input fields:

Starting from the button itself (`this`) you look for the closest parent container of type `td`, then find all its siblings and their children of type `input`. The result is a jquery object with all the inputs of one table row. Then do the copying of values from the first (`flds.eq(0)`) to the rest of them all (`flds.slice(1)`).

```js
$('.table a.btn').click(function() {
  var flds = $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('input');
  flds.slice(1).val(flds.eq(0).val());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table"><thead><tr>
 <th scope="col">#</th><th scope="col">First</th><th scope="col">Last</th>
</tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a>
</td><td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1"> 
 </td><td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="11">
 </td><td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="11">
 </td></tr><tr><td>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a>
</td><td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2"> 
 </td><td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
 </td><td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
</td></tr><tr><td>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1">Copy</a>
</td><td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3"> 
</td><td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3">
</td><td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3">
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```